# How to filter normalized nested JSON data with no array?

Tags: javascript, json, redux, normalizr

after use `normalizr` library I have the following normalized JSON object result in the Redux state of my application:

```
  { 
    sports: {
        byId: {
          1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Soccer',
            slug: 'soccer'
          },
          2: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Basketball',
            slug: 'basketball'
          },
          3: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'American Football',
            slug: 'american-football'
          }
        },
        allIds: [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3'
        ]
      },
      competitions: {
        byId: {
          '1': {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Competition 1',
            short_name: 'Comp 1',
            slug: 'comp-1',
            sport: 1,
            status: {
             is_live: false 
           }
          },
          '2': {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Competition 2',
            short_name: 'Comp 2',
            slug: 'comp-2',
            sport: 1,
            status: {
             is_live: true 
           }
          },
          '3': {
            id: 3,
            name: 'National Basketball League',
            short_name: 'NBA',
            slug: 'national-basketball-league',
            sport_slug: 'basketball',
            sport: 3,
            status: {
             is_live: true 
           }
          }
        },
        allIds: [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3'
        ]
     }
```

What I want achieve: I want a list of `competitions` filtered/categorized by `sports`.

How can I do that?

Also I want to be able to group `competitions` by it's `status.is_live`.

So how can I get an list of `competitions` breakdown by `sport` that `status.is_live` equals true and `competitions` `status.is_live` equals false?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [lodash](https://lodash.com), you can write a `.groupBy` function pretty easily ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)). You'll need to loop over the output object and reassign its children values with a for instead of using `.mapValues`.

I used lodash in the example, just to point out the logic.

> **Note:** I'd remove the grouping in the data in the original response, and let the client do this on its own - it's easier to work on an unsorted array and filter/map that instead of working against values from an object that has redundant keys (since they represent groups by Id)

```js
let data = {
  sports: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Soccer',
        slug: 'soccer'
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Basketball',
        slug: 'basketball'
      },
      3: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'American Football',
        slug: 'american-football'
      }
    },
    allIds: [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3'
    ]
  },
  competitions: {
    byId: {
      '1': {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Competition 1',
        short_name: 'Comp 1',
        slug: 'comp-1',
        sport: 1,
        status: {
          is_live: false
        }
      },
      '2': {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Competition 2',
        short_name: 'Comp 2',
        slug: 'comp-2',
        sport: 1,
        status: {
          is_live: true
        }
      },
      '3': {
        id: 3,
        name: 'National Basketball League',
        short_name: 'NBA',
        slug: 'national-basketball-league',
        sport_slug: 'basketball',
        sport: 3,
        status: {
          is_live: true
        }
      }
    },
    allIds: [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3'
    ]
  }
}

let competitions = Object.values(data.competitions.byId)

// _.chain(arr) keeps returning `lodash` objects
// so I don't have to call it separately for every action
let filteredCompetitions = _.chain(competitions)
  .groupBy(i => i.status.is_live)
  .mapValues(i => _.groupBy(i, 'sport'))
  .value() // returns the final value
  
console.log(filteredCompetitions)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I tried this and I think it works without have status/is_live reference on `sport`.

`let filteredCompetitions = _.chain(competitions)
  .groupBy('sport')
  .value()
  // returns the final value
  
  _.forEach(filteredCompetitions, function(value, key) {
  filteredCompetitions[key] = _.groupBy(filteredCompetitions[key], function(item) {
    return item.status.is_live;
  });
});
  
console.log(filteredCompetitions)`

Maybe have more elegant way to do that ?